# What is the letter meaning in XYDATA of JCAMP-DX (NMR) files?

Tags: python, file-format

I've been downloading some JCAMP-DX format files of [HNMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_nuclear_magnetic_resonance) (proton nuclear magnetic resonance) spectra, however I can't seem to parse the files. I tried a Python [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jcamp), but I found it wouldn't read my files. I also tried getting a clearer picture from some [documentation](http://www.jcamp-dx.org/protocols/dxnmr01.pdf), however it did not clarify what is confusing me.

Okay, so here is the issue. The ##XYDATA has letters (and sometimes other characters like @) among the what should be the data points, and I don't know what that means. Here is an example line from a file illustrating this problem (I've bolded the unusual characters):

-227.8**b**6764**b**6121**b**6335**b**4194**b**8691**a**8842**b**5265**b**5693**a**9270**b**1411**b**4623**b**3552**c**0618\r\n

Centrally my question is this: how do I understand/parse the letters in the example line of data?

UPDATES:

I found that there is some more [information](http://wwwchem.uwimona.edu.jm:1104/software/jcampdx.html) about the letters as a compression format, but I am unsure I fully understand the map.

I tried these maps, but I don't see anything resembling a delimiter to distinguish x and y values.

```
positive_SQZ_digits = {'@':'0', 'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3', 'D':'4', 'E':'5', 'F':'6', 'G':'7', 'H':'8', 'I':'9'}
negative_SQZ_digits = {' ':'0', 'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3', 'd':'4', 'e':'5', 'f':'6', 'g':'7', 'h':'8', 'i':'9'}
positive_DIF_digits = {'%':'0', 'J':'1', 'K':'2', 'L':'3', 'M':'4', 'N':'5', 'O':'6', 'P':'7', 'Q':'8', 'R':'9'}
negative_DIF_digits = {' ':'0', 'j':'1', 'k':'2', 'l':'3', 'm':'4', 'n':'5', 'o':'6', 'p':'7', 'q':'8', 'r':'9'}
positive_DUP_digits = {' ':'0', 'S':'1', 'T':'2', 'U':'3', 'V':'4', 'W':'5', 'X':'6', 'Y':'7', 'Z':'8', 's':'9'}
```

Comment: I'm having a very similar, possibly the same, problem.  It would be helpful if you could provide sample code and a sample JCAMP-DX file, along with the error messages (if any) that result from running your code.

Comment: @CurtF. I have not checked if it always works, but I found that the aforementioned python library has xrange in it, a python2 function, in it even when installing with pip3. I replaced the xranges with range, and that seems to let me read files. I will update when I test more cases.

Comment: @CurtF. Unfortunately, the library still does not handle these unusual characters...